# Why this zend example stops working when I add a hash to the form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm following this example tutorial

project code: http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/zf-tutorial-layoutform.zip

tutorial: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/a-form-in-your-layout/

The project code runs as expected, until I add a hash element to the form. All I do is add this code in the form under application/forms/Signup.php

```
$hash = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('hash');
$hash->setSalt('mysalt');
$this->addElement($hash);
```

This extra bit of code throws everything off. When I submit the form now, it gives me the error that the 2 tokens don't match.

Some troubleshooting:

- The problem is not the hash itself because it works fine in my other examples.
- I think has to do with how the request is being handled in this example, but not sure what the problem is exactly. I thought it had to do with the hop count, but when I edit Zend_Form_Element_Hash and changed the hop count from 1 to 100, I still got the same error.

That's the extent of troubleshooting I could think of at my level of expertise with Zend. So thought it's time to ask the big brains. I'm hoping someone can figure it out.

Comment: As the hash element makes use of zend_session that might be a problem. another thing to check might be the hops until validation as the hash expires after one hop (or after a timeout).

Comment: No it's hardcoded. But you might want to compare the session content and the submited form data. ($_SESSION vs $_POST) and remove any redirects for debuging.

Comment: Not directly. But it's more then one if your browserbar shows anything else then the forms target. But if you don't redirect you really should check the $_SESSION/$_POST.

Comment: Do you have this live anywhere? It works fine for me.

Comment: @jakenoble It works for you even after you've added the hash element to the form? If so, could you please upload your project and post as a separate answer.

Comment: All I did was add the code you posted and it worked fine. Where are you using this code? It sounds like something to do with your environment

Comment: @jakenoble, Thanks for the hint. It turned out to be a setting in my bootstrap.php. Can you post your comment as an answer. The 200 points get removed from my account regardless, so I might as well award them to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for you even after you've added the hash element to the form? If so, could you please upload your project and post as a separate answer.

All I did was add the code you posted and it worked fine. Where are you using this code? It sounds like something to do with your environment?

Answer (score 0):

From: [Zend_Form_Element_Hash](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.hash)

This element provides protection from CSRF attacks on forms, ensuring the data is submitted by the user session that generated the form and not by a rogue script. Protection is achieved by adding a hash element to a form and verifying it when the form is submitted.

The name of the hash element should be unique. We recommend using the salt option for the element- two hashes with same names and different salts would not collide:

`$form->addElement('hash', 'no_csrf_foo', array('salt' => 'unique'));`

You can set the salt later using the setSalt($salt) method.

Internally, the element stores a unique identifier using Zend_Session_Namespace, and checks for it at submission (checking that the TTL has not expired). The 'Identical' validator is then used to ensure the submitted hash matches the stored hash.

The 'formHidden' view helper is used to render the element in the form.

I will try:

`$form->addElement('hash', 'unique_form_name', array('salt' => 'unique_salt'));`

I do not see unique form/hash name in your code and this is why tokens do not mach.

Comment: Isn't the string `hash` that is being used to create the element its unique name?

Comment: The name is not the problem. It works just fine with the name "hash".